# Divide a variable of date and time into two seperate variables, one date and the other time

Tags: r

I have a dataset in which one of the variables date and time with the format 01JUN17:00:00:00. I am trying to analyze the effect of just the time of day on my data, so I would like to know if there is a way to separate the variable into two separate variables so I can isolate the time.

Comment: What you have there, does it correspond to 00:00 on 1 June 17?

Comment: What is the structure of your data frame? Is that variable a string? If so then I suggest to convert it to  datetime(`as.POSIXct`) and work with that...extract days, hours, ...etc

Comment: Use the package `lubridate` to parse the string into a Date object, and then extract the appropriate parts (date, time, month, year, etc.) from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a dataset in which one of the variables date and time with the format 01JUN17:00:00:00. I am trying to analyze the effect of just the time of day on my data, so I would like to know if there is a way to separate the variable into two separate variables so I can isolate the time.

The Tidyverse\Tidyr\Dplyr function separate() can do this. Separate your variable at the 8th character from the left.

```
library(tidyverse)
my_data <- tibble(my_date_time = c("01JUN17:00:00:00", "01JUN17:01:00:00", "01JUN17:02:00:00"))
my_data
my_data <- separate(data=my_data, col=my_date_time, into=c("my_date","my_time"), sep=8)
my_data
#the new columns are chracter strings, use the readr::parse_time() function to convert
my_data$my_time <- parse_time(my_data$my_time)
my_data
```